# Is it a good practice to use list language construct in php?

Tags: php, keyword

Is it better (safer/more readable) to use `list` or to assign values one after another ?

Examples :

With `list` :

```
$head = '';
if(strpos($data, "\r\n") !== false)
    list($status, $head) = explode("\r\n", $data, 2);
else
    $status = $data;
```

Without `list` :

```
$head = '';
$components = explode("\r\n", $data, 2);
$status = $components[0];

if(count($components) === 2) //Or isset($components[1])
    $head = $components[1];
```

What's the preferred way to write this piece of code ?

Comment: Do whatever is the easiest to maintain. To me, having named variables that describe their values is better then array notation.

Comment: This question might be better suited on [codereview.se].

Comment: Some IDE's have trouble introspecting variables created from functions like extract, compact, and list.

Comment: You might need to ensure your string really has enough variables after exploding or you will get undefined variables and errors. Otherwise, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the use case `list` may end up causing you problems. Conventionally defining the values however would not.
Notes from http://PHP.net:

> `list()` only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0.

.

> Modification of the array during `list()` execution (e.g. using list($a, $b) = $b) results in undefined behavior.

.

> . . .if you are using arrays with indices you usually expect the order of the indices in the array the same you wrote in the list() from left to right; which it isn't. It's assigned in the reverse order.

Clearly using `list` can cause some unexpected behavior, and it definitely isn't the most common way to do this. This makes `list` bad for readability because it's unconventional. 
As far as I know there are *no* benefits to using `list` , and I would assume that it is slower.

Comment: Thank you, it's the kind of response I expected.